# Laravel polymorphic-relationship many to many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I'm having some trouble figuring out the polymorphic relationships.
I've read the documentation but for me it is quite confusing.

Hope anyone has the time to help me a bit to understanding it.
What I'm trying to do is to have a very simple tag system for some wallpapers.

I started a new test project just to get this working.

I have 3 models: Wallpaper, Tag and WallpaperTag

```
class Wallpaper extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'wallpaper_id';
    protected $table = 'wallpapers';
    protected $guarded = ['wallpaper_id'];

    /**
     * Get all the tags assigned to this wallpaper
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        //
    }

}

class Tag extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'tag_id';
    protected $table = 'tags';
    protected $guarded = ['tag_id'];

    /**
     * Get all wallpapers that have this given tag
     */
    public function wallpapers()
    {
        //
    }
}

class WallpaperTag extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'wallpaper_tag_id';
    protected $table = 'wallpaper_tags';
    protected $guarded = ['wallpaper_tag_id'];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     * Wallpaper relation
     */
    public function wallpaper()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Wallpaper','wallpaper_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     * Tag relation
     */
    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag','tag_id');
    }

}
```

The wallpapers table in this test project contains only `wallpaper_id`

The tags table contanis a `tag_id` and a `tag`

The wallpaper_tags table contains a foreign key for both `tags.tag_id` and `wallpapers.wallpaper_id`

I've set it up like this so wallpapers can share tags without duplicating them. The problem is that I really dont understand the polymorphic relations and the example in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

Can anyone here 'spoonfeed' how this would work? :') Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: I like to have the id's according the table name. Just a preference. :) But every wallpaper can have multiple tags. Tags can belong to multiple wallpapers.

Tag 1 can be on Wallpaper 1, 2, 3 and 4. WallpaperTag would then have 4 rows Tag 1 to Wallpaper 1, Tag 1 to wallpaper 2 etc..

Comment: Alright, so from what I understood form your DB structure, you are looking to use `ManyToMany` relationship. Because your `Wallpaper` and `Tag` classes contain only ids to themselves.  And you hold a third table to create the relationship between them. Can you confirm this DB structure?

Comment: Yea thats correct. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are trying to create a relationship with `ManyToMany` between 2 tables, which in the DB needs a 3rd table to allow you to create such relationship.

This is due to the fact that one `Wallpaper` can have many `Tag` and vice versa! For such you need a 3rd table that holds that information accordingly.

The 3rd table is only holding ids in relationship to your 2 main tables. This allows the flexibility you are looking for, while your Object tables can actually hold information specific to them, without you having to duplicate it.

If you were to store the relationship ids on both tables you would be forced to duplicate your data and that is just something you do not wish on databases! Imagine having to update 1000 rows because it is basically the same wallpaper but with so many different tags.

Anyway, below is the code that should be get you going:

1. You do need to create a class to represent your relationship table  (Kudos on the `WallpaperTag` class! That is the one!);
2. You do not touch that class anymore, do not add belongs or any other function!
3. You create the relationships on the main classes `Wallpaper` and `Tag`;

```
    class Wallpaper extends Model
    {
        ...
        public function tags()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'wallpaper_tag', 'tag_id', 'wallpaper_id');
        }
    }

    class Tag extends Model
    {
        ...
        public function wallpapers()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Wallpaper', 'wallpaper_tag', 'wallpaper_id', 'tag_id');
        }
    }

    class WallpaperTag extends Model
    {

    }
```

Laravel should create a relationship between your classes and map it accordingly to the correct 3rd table to sort the search for you.

If you follow the semantics all you needed was the class name. If ids are to change, then you will need to start telling Laravel what id column names it should be looking for as you deviate from the normal behaviour. It still finds it, just needs some guidance on the names! Hence why we start adding more parameters to the relationships `belongsTo` or `hasMany` etc :)

**Pivot Table Migration**

You do not need an id for your pivot table since your **primary key** is a combination of the **two foreign keys** from the other tables.

```
  $table->bigInteger('wallpaper_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
  $table->foreign('wallpaper_id')->references('wallpaper_id')
        ->on('wallpaper')->onDelete('cascade');

  $table->bigInteger('tag_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
  $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('tag_id')
        ->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Let me know if it helped! :3

Comment: Okay so I tried this, but I'm left with the error message I get all the time basically.
This error message pops up when I try to call `...->tags()` on a wallpaper wich has tags.

Error here: https://pastebin.com/FvVP4MWp

Comment: Apologies, the second argument is the relationship table, whilst the 3rd and 4th would be the changed ids. Will adapt the answer so you can give it a try :)

Comment: can you share the migration for your 3rd table? The WallpaperTag?

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball updated the answer with a few changes to the migration class and also the relationship on the Classes themselves :)

Comment: Holy damn. That worked! Just ran the test to verify. Well damn, so laravel basically does the morphing for me as long as the 3rd and 4th param are set in the belongsTo etc. Thank you!